# Why does Aarthi Devanathan have a pitchfork in her name, and why does she care so much about Parenting all of a sudden?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I've noticed that Aarthi Devanathan is suddenly super active on this site, editing new titles and being super available in chat. What's going on? Why is she here so much? And why does she have a Ψ in her name?

[image: profile for Aarthi Devanathan Ψ on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

Comment: This question is obsolete since CHAOS, and the attendant pitchfork symbol, no longer are in use or part of SE.

Comment: That's quite sad really. I know it was a while back, but :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I'm here to help improve and promote parenting! If you've missed the info about the CHAOS team (aka the Pitchforks or Forky Folk, depending on who you talk to about us), you can learn more [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100137/what-is-the-meaning-of-chaos-is-it-related-to-the-psi-character) about the CHAOS initiative.

For an example of what I've been asked to do in the past, check out [this](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345/who-is-aarthi-devanathan-and-why-is-she-changing-so-many-posts) post over at my other assignment, DIY.

I'll edit titles, do some site promotion, and so forth. Feel free to ask me anything; I usually hang out in the Parenting Chatroom anyway, and I'm happy to respond to pings anytime. :)

Comment: On behalf of the community and the mods, let me extend an "official"(?) welcome to you!You've got to be quick if you want to edit titles :-) the mods are pretty fast with that. But we very much appreciate your site promotion efforts and general support!

Comment: #include what Torben said. :)